# How to expand the sides of a cube while it rotate?

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to expand the sides of a cube while it rotate like in [this pen](https://codepen.io/CompuIves/pen/Ojjdoj?editors=1100).

I have tried to create a cube that will spin along `x` axis but while doing so I want it to also expand its sides after some duration.

Below is my code...

```css
.wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.cube-wrap {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-perspective: 2000px;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% -500px;
}

.single-box {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #60c2ef;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(-200px) rotateX(15deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;            
}

.box {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 1.5s infinite linear;
}

.side-front { 
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(20px);
}

.side-back { 
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(20px);
}

.side-top {
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(20px);
}

.side-bottom { 
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(20px); 
}

.side-left { 
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(20px); 
}

.side-right { 
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(20px); 
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cube-wrap">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="single-box side-back"></div>
            <div class="single-box side-top"></div>
            <div class="single-box side-bottom"></div>
            <div class="single-box side-left"></div>
            <div class="single-box side-right"></div>
           <div class="single-box side-front"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code will rotate along `x` axis. It is fine. Along with that, say after 3s or so, I want the cube to rotate slowly and expand along the sides... How can I do it? Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

This might sound like a stupid answer.. but the answer is actually already in the Codepen that you provided yourself.

In case you're unfamiliair with sass/codepen.
In codepen you can select the dropdown icon and choose for **view copiled css**

I would suggest to copy the already existing code and then customize it to your own needs.
You could also fork the pen and change it in the codepen environment.